# How to select a drop down item , based on another drop down value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
$("#Server_RackID").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Server/LoadDataCenterByRackID", { rackid: idDC },
            function (DCData) {
                var select = $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID");
                select.empty();
                $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val() = DCData.Value;

            });
        });
```

The idea is that when the user change the Server_RackID drop down , then I need to select the Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID based on the return id. The action method which will be called looks like this:-

```
 [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Server")]
     public JsonResult LoadDataCenterByRackID(string rackid)
     {
         var datacenter = repository.FindRack(Convert.ToInt32(rackid));



         return Json(new { Value = datacenter.DataCenterID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

But when I run my code I got the following error:-

> 0x800a138b - JavaScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function
>   result

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to the val() function, and not to "#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID". So instead of :

```
$("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val() = DCData.Value;
```

try

```
$("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val(DCData.Value);
```

Comment: i tried this $("#Server_RackID").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Server/LoadDataCenterByRackID", { rackid: idDC },
            function (DCData) {
                var select = $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID");
                select.empty();
                $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val(DCData.Value);
               
            });
        }); // but this will empty the DatacenterId drop down list, instead i need to select the item that have the .Value.. can you advice please?

Answer (score 0):

You wrong usage of `val()` is the reason you are getting it messed up. Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for the documentation for `val()`, it must be `$(identifier).val(value)`. Try this

```
$("#Server_RackID").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Server/LoadDataCenterByRackID", { rackid: idDC },
            function (DCData) {
                $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val(DCData.Value);
            });
        });
```